# Why base64 image is big ? xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, base64

I am facing one error sometimes, when I try get a picture from user gallery.
I get the picture in a Stream object, convert it to a base64 and I send it using a post function.
Sometimes The program says that the image path is big and, because of that, its not possible send the url.
I heard that its cause the image size but I am not sure about it...
Does someone know what really causes a Big base64 string? How can I solve that?

Comment: Its an encoding format that converts 3 bytes to 4 bytes. The bloat is expected. You might need to implement some level of compression on client level for your images - or update your online api to accept larger files in parts! like accept multi-part requests.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow something similar to this:

http://jamessdixon.wordpress.com/2013/10/01/handling-images-in-webapi/

Maybe you need make some change in your web api like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
   public HttpResponseMessage UploadImage(int ID)
   {
       var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
       if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
       {
           Request.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync().Wait();
           Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider()).ContinueWith((task) =>
           {
               MultipartMemoryStreamProvider provider = task.Result;
               foreach (HttpContent content in provider.Contents)
               {
                  Stream stream = content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
                  Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
                  var testName = content.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name;
                  String filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/");
                  String fullPath = Path.Combine(filePath, ID.ToString()+".jpg");
                  image.Save(fullPath);
               }
           });
          return result;
       }
       else
       {
           throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted"));
       }

   }
```

After making sure your api web works well you should change from `Stream` to `byte[]`

In your Xamarin code try this:

```cs
  public async Task PostItem(String Controller, String Method, int ID, byte[] item) 
  {
      using (var client = CreateClient ()) {
      var da = new ByteArrayContent(item);

        try{
            var multi = new MultipartContent();
            multi.Add(da);
            var response = await client.PostAsync (Controller + "/" +Method + "/?ID=" +ID, multi);
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
           Console.Write(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

For more infomation see [MultipartContent](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Net.Http.MultipartContent/) class documentation